# Object class name in perl

Tags: perl, class, object, reference

I am kinda beginner in **perl** and I need know how can I check object class name.

My code is:

```
 foreach my $y (keys %$x) {
   print "$y\t$x->{$y}\n";
 }
```

with output:

```
154176568       [object HTMLImageElement]
146292140       [object HTMLDocument]
153907016       [object HTMLImageElement]
```

I need to print just keys that are `HTMLImageElement` objects.

Now, question is:

(1) How can I **check** the class name

(2) How can I **get**/print class name

Comment: Does the test code print, literally, `[object HTMLImageElement]`? If so then it looks like the object has a stringification method. If that is the case you could test the result of stringification using `"$x->{$y}" eq '[object HTMLImageElement]'`. Similarly you could get the class name by forcing stringification, e.g. `my $class_name = "$x->{$y}";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [the source for JE](https://metacpan.org/source/SPROUT/JE-0.058), it looks like `JE::Object::Proxy` is a subclass of `JE::Object`, and `JE::Object` has a stringification method (`use overload fallback => 1, ... '""' => 'to_string' ...`).

So when you do `print "$y\t$x->{$y}\n";`, this is printing the result of stringifying `$x->{$y}`.

You can stringify the object by putting it in double quotes, so `"$x->{$y}"`. This expression will then have values such as you saw being printed, e.g. `'[object HTMLImageElement]'`.

If you want to pick up only **HTMLImageElement** objects, then you could check for these using an expression like

```
"$x->{$y}" eq '[object HTMLImageElement]'
```

If you especially want to extract the string `'HTMLImageElement'` from the stringified value, you could do that using a regexp, e.g.

```
("$x->{$y}" =~ m{^\[object (.*)\]$}so)[0]
```

THOUGH, looking at [the source for JE::Object::Proxy](https://metacpan.org/source/SPROUT/JE-0.058/lib/JE/Object/Proxy.pm), `JE::Object::Proxy` has a method `class` which might perhaps return the name of the class that the object is a proxy for. So you might be able to get the class name using `$x->{$y}->class`, and then be able to test that directly as in  `$x->{$y}->class eq 'HTMLImageElement'`.

Answer (score 4):

In Perl all classes magically extend the `UNIVERSAL` package. It has a method called `isa()` that you can use to do this:

```
 foreach my $y (keys %$x) {
   if( $x->{$y}->isa('HTMLImageElement') ) {
      print "$y\t$x->{$y}\n";
   }
 }
```

Comment: This is the proper way, if you are trying to check whether it is a certain type, but will not permit you to display the class type.

Comment: And how can I get class name for `$x->{$y}`? Looks like `isa` is for checking only, correct?

Comment: It does not work, and it returns `false` every time. If I use `isa('JE::Object::Proxy')`, then it returns `true` each time. :(

Comment: @stackoverflow - Such is the way of Perl. The only way to return the name is to use ref() but as I pointed out that won't always work. However it seems the package you're using is doing some kind of voodoo magic behind the scenes that's not allowing isa to work either.  One option would be to subclass your classes and implement the isa() method yourself. How are you creating the objects in the first place?

Comment: I am using `WWW::Scripter`. I cannot implement the `isa()`, as classes and objects are out of my code.

Comment: This answer is a red herring because the objects are `JE::Object::Proxy` objects rather than Perl objects. Fortunately, it appears to be a CPAN module, so we can see what it's doing. See my answer beginning "Looking at the source for JE..."

Answer (score 1):

If you want a string indicating the class name, use ref($object).  This will return the reference type for a variable, which for perl objects, ends up being the package of the blessed object.

If you want to simply check if a variable is an instance of a certain class, use the isa() method. For instance:

```
if ($obj->isa('Animal::Dog')) {
   push @dogs, $obj;
}
```

Comment: This won't always work if his class is extended from another class. See my answer about isa()

Comment: I guess we both assumed different meanings for how he wanted to 'check'.  I assumed that from his example he wanted to see it (through printing), while you assumed he was trying to do a programmatic check.

Comment: Does not work, as `ref` returns `JE::Object::Proxy` for all of them.

Comment: Well, it likely did work, its just that your object is a proxy of another class.  You'll likely have to traverse the inheritance graph if you want to know what the proxy is wrapping.  Be careful, though, in general you shouldn't have to know the type of an object to use it. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing.

Comment: Problem is, that even `[object HTMLDocument]` returns same `ref`, so this way I cannot tell if it is `[object HTMLImageElement]` or not.

Comment: It sounds like you are using some DOM library, and trying to use the object type to determine what type of node you are looking at? This is most likely not how the library was intended to be used.  What library are you using?